# Type error that shows on console, but not on pythontutor.com

Tags: python, list

Ok, so I have a block of code that I am trying to debug, and I usually use Pythontutor.com to step through the code to see where it is going wrong.  Problem is, the exact code works on the website, but not in my console.

```
row = []
row.append("Acid Arrow")
testList = ['Detect', 'Discern', 'Summon', 'Call', 'Binding']
nameList = row[0].split(' ')
print testList, nameList
a = list(set(testList) & set(nameList))
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\D&D\SpellBag>livingSpell.py
['Detect', 'Discern', 'Summon', 'Call', 'Binding'] ['Acid', 'Arrow']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Dropbox\D&D\SpellBag\livingSpell.py", line 121, in <module>
    sb = spellBook(r'allSpells.csv')
  File "C:\Users\User\Dropbox\D&D\SpellBag\livingSpell.py", line 27, in __init__
    a = list(set(testList) & set(nameList))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The above code works flawlessly on PythonTutor, but fails when I run it in the console.  What it is intended to do is check if a word from the list is in the spell name, which if any of them are, the spell is passed over and it moves on.  It should be returning an empty list, but instead I get the error.

Comment: Did you assign something to `list` or `set` in the console, perhaps? What do `type(list)` and `type(set)` return?

Comment: show All of livingSpell.py and ALL the output on your console

Answer (score 2):

The line that has the error is `a = list(set(testList) & set(nameList))`, and the error says "'str' object is not callable." This means the Python interpreter tried to call a function and found out it wasn't actually a function. This is the same error you would get if you typed `"bad_code"()`, since the string `"bad_code"` is not a function.

It's impossible to say exactly which of the two is having an issue, but either `list` or `set` has been overwritten and is now a string rather than the default functions provided in Python. That snippet of code works fine by itself in pythontutor.com because the offending line of code happens somewhere before it in your file (the error says you have 22 lines of code beforehand). In fact, if you started a blank file and only had the snippet you posted here on StackOverflow, it would run perfectly. Check for anything like `list = ...` or `set = ...` in your original source code.

It is a somewhat common convention in Python to avoid naming conflicts with reserved words (list, set, or, if, with, while, etc...) by appending an underscore to the name. In this case, that would mean writing either `list_ = ...` or `set_ = ...`. A good coding practice in general though would be to come up with a specific name for your variable that describes it exactly. For example, you might use `used_spell_list` instead of `list` (just guessing...I have no idea how this was overwritten).

Comment: This was it, I had used the word list as an iterator on a for loop looping over a set of lists, so it made sense there, fixed now and I'm off to the races.... or killing my party with proceduraly generated monsters off of a huge database of spells... you know, fun stuff.

Comment: Haha, nothing like a TPK. I'd love to have a look at it when you finish. This strikes me as very D&D-esque.